# Windows C++: Get driver device ID

Tags: c++, windows, driver, device-driver

I'm writing a C++ program that should check Driver Device ID.

My input is the driver name as it should appear in the Device Manager.

I tried to Google, and I figured that:

- I could get the driver pointer using this sample code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682619%28VS.85%29.aspx
- I should use IRP_MN_QUERY_ID function to get the device ID- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551679(v=vs.85).aspx.

However, I couldn't find any examples or code snippets for how to actually do it, and how those two functions connect?

I have no experience in drivers, sample code will be very appreciated...

Answer (score -1):

On windows there are no device ids (as name =) ). Device matches by hardware id and compatible ids. From this ids system generate instance id - uniquely identifies the device on specific port on bus. You can get hardware/compatible id without sending IRPs, by using IoGetDeviceProperty function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549203(v=vs.85).aspx), it`s more easy than roll up your own IRP.

Comment: wrong. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541237(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: my bad, i forgot about this small detail, but this is instance specific id. And second : i not understand that you wish to enumerate devices from usermode programm. You need to use SetupApi for this, start from SetupDiGetClassDevs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069(v=vs.85).aspx), SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo, etc